# How to manage supervisord restart gracefully with gunicorn?

Tags: gunicorn, supervisord, supervised-learning

I have scenario in which i want gunicorn workers to acknowledge and fulfill ongoing requests before supervisord starts after stopping(restart).

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: May this will be usefull. http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/signals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Supervisor configuration as autostart and autorestart as true.

Then kill the gunicorn by

```
 kill -HUP `cat /tmp/process.pid`
```

It will shutdown gracefully hence processing all requests and supervisor will restart it according to the configurations.

You can also use reload of gunicorn as it sends HUP signal.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, you can to reload your app by sending HUP signal by: `pkill -HUP gunicorn`.

Because the `/var/run/` directory is missing this `pid`:

```
find /var/run/ -iname '*gunicorn*' | wc -l
0
```

See the official Gunicorn docs, http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html

and `man 1 pkill`